# Calculating the integral with an undefined function f(x)

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

I am having a problem with an excersice of calculating the integral

I= $\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{1+f(x)}\,dx$

and we know that $f(x)f(a-x)=1$ , **$a>0$**  and **$f(x)$ is continous and positive on the interval $[0,a]$**

i've tried manipulating the expression with the fact that $f(x)= \ \frac{1}{f(a-x)} $ in order to find something to cancel or something that makes me solve the integral "nicely"

However after 20 minutes i have no idea what to do, or what i am missing

so if anyone could give me a tip or point me in the right direction i would appreciate it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$
\int_0^a\frac{1}{1+f(x)}\,dx = \int_0^a\frac{1}{1+f(a-x)}\,dx = \int_0^a\frac{1}{1+\frac 1{f(x)}}\,dx = \int_0^a\frac{f(x)}{1+f(x)}\,dx,
$$
where in the first transformation we changed variables $x = a-y$. Hence,
$$
2I = I + I = \int_0^a\frac{1}{1+f(x)}\,dx + \int_0^a\frac{f(x)}{1+f(x)}\,dx = \int_0^a1\,dx = a.
$$
Thus, $I = \frac a2$.

Comment: I don't understand why $\int_0^a\frac{1}{1+f(x)}\,dx = \int_0^a\frac{1}{1+f(a-x)}\,dx$ because we don't got $f(x)=f(a-x)$ we got $f(x)=1/f(a-x)$. Help?

Comment: @PrimeMover Change of variables. I edited my answer.

Comment: I'm still a bit slow, wouldn't that make the second integral negative? $dx = -dy$ and all that?

Comment: @PrimeMover No. Watch the integral boundaries. $-\int_a^0 = \int_0^a$

Comment: Oh right okay no worries

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand why changing the variables still leads to $f(a-x)$ and not $f(a-y)$ and $dx$ instead of $dy$

Comment: @Ramirogenta $\int_0^ag(y)\,dy = \int_0^ag(x)\,dx$. It doesn't matter which letter I use as the integration variable.

Comment: @Ramirogenta To clarify further, the $x$ exists only inside the integral, so, technically, the $x$ in the first integral is not related to the $x$ in the second integral. It just happens to be easier to use the same letter for both of them.

Answer (score 8):

If the answer is independent of $f(x)$, then you can choose one consistent with the stated conditions, e.g., $f(x)=1$, in which case we find:

$$\int\limits_{x=0}^a \frac{1}{1 + 1} dx = \frac{a}{2}.$$

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but we need to be careful. The question does not actually say that the answer is independent of $f$.

Comment: @BrianDrake:  True enough, but one *can* say that $a/2$ is *one* valid solution!

Answer (score 4):

Same answer, different approach.  By symmetry,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^a\frac1{1+f(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\left(\int_0^a\frac1{1+f(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^a\frac1{1+f(a-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\tag1\\
&=\frac12\int_0^a\left(\frac1{1+f(x)}+\frac1{1+f(a-x)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=\frac12\int_0^a\frac{\color{#C00}{1}+f(x)+\color{#C00}{1}+f(a-x)}{\color{#090}{1}+f(x)+f(a-x)+\color{#090}{f(x)f(a-x)}}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag3\\
&=\frac12\int_0^a\frac{\color{#C00}{2}+f(x)+f(a-x)}{\color{#090}{2}+f(x)+f(a-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag4\\[3pt]
&=\frac a2\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: by substituting $x\mapsto a-x$, we get $\int_0^a\frac1{1+f(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^a\frac1{1+f(a-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$
$\phantom{\text{(1):}}$ average the two
$(2)$: sum of integrals is the integral of the sum
$(3)$: $\frac1u+\frac1v=\frac{u+v}{uv}$
$(4)$: the sum of the integrands is $1$ since $f(x)f(a-x)=1$
$(5)$: integrate

Comment: I don't understand why you are adding, or why did you separate the original integral into to with the second one being the same but with $$f(a-x)$$ would'nt that just change the value?

Comment: Again: Change of variables. Or as robjohn likes to say: "By symmetry". ;-)

Comment: @Ramirogenta: substituting $x\mapsto a-x$, if done consistently, leaves the integral unchanged. If you prefer, you can add a step by substituting $x=a-y$ then another substituting $y=x$.

Comment: You wrote “the sum of the integrands is $1$”, which is the *result* of equation $(3)$. Perhaps it would be better to explain the *source* of equation $(3)$, like you did for the other equations. In this case, it involves $f(x)f(a-x)=1$.

Comment: @BrianDrake: I'm sorry, I have added a step that I had previously thought unnecessary. I guess I was wrong.